# Python open fifo blocks forever

Tags: python, named-pipes

I'm trying to implement IPC using named pipes in Python, but there is a problem. `open` blocks the process

```
import os
path = '/tmp/fifo'
os.mkfifo(path)
fifo = open(path, 'w') # never returns
```

Same with `open(path, 'r')`

What am I doing wrong?

Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 13):

Figured this out. `open` blocks until the pipe is open on the other side

With `os.open`, the statement will be nonblocking if os.O_NONBLOCK is given as a flag. Nonblocking may not work on your OS. I believe it works on Unix distros but not Windows.

Comment: Life saver comment.

Comment: This answer is too inaccurate, thus error prone. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76523154/780703)

Answer (score 0):

**Correction** to the accpeted answer, which is *too inaccurate*, if not totally wrong. Below is from [`man fifo(7)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) of Linux:

First, blocking mode opening. This is what OP found:

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

Non-blocking, read-only opening case is:

> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening for read-only succeeds
> even  if no one has opened on the write side yet

But non-blocking, write-only opening is dangerous:

> and opening for write-only fails with ENXIO (no such device or
> address) *unless the other end has already been opened*.

There is a workaround, namely read-write opening. But this also needs care:

> Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking
> mode.   POSIX  leaves  this behavior undefined.  This can be used to open a FIFO for writing while there are no readers available.

A practical caution follows in the manual page :)

> A process that uses both ends of  the  connection  in
> order to communicate with itself should be, very careful to avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score -1):

the function `os.mkfifo(path)` create the path is needed (if all the folder does not exists it build all the path).

so, you need to add the file name like this: `fifo = open(path + file, 'r')`

Generally, FIFOs are used as rendezvous between “client” and “server” type processes: the server opens the FIFO for reading, and the client opens it for writing. **Note that mkfifo() doesn’t open the FIFO — it just creates the rendezvous point**

Comment: `path + file` will just concatenate strings, and in my case `/tmp` defiantly exists, no need to create it. `os.mkfifo` creates the file successfully ```ls -latrh /tmp/pipe 
prw-r--r-- 1 oleg users 0 Oct  3 08:30 /tmp/pipe```

Answer (score -1):

According to [os.mkfifo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo), you need to use 
`fifo = open(path, dir_fd='w')`

Comment: Doesn't work. `os.mkfifo(path, dir_fd='w')` throws `TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not str` and `dir_fd=os.O_WRONLY` doesn't. But the result is the same: `open` blocks forever

Comment: `dir_fd` should be a file descriptor, read/write flag.